# Why does my script work in powershell ISE but not when it is in a .ps1 file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

It used to work but now it suddently terminates less than a second after being opened. I set the execution policy to unrestricted & re-installed Windows yet it still does not work...
The .ps1 shows up for 1 second in task manager before windows security health service when it's run using .vbs & then disappears: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hccak.png

Here's the script (its purpose is to show notification messages):

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$notifyobj = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$notifyobj.icon = "c:/users/work/Pictures/icon.ico"
$notifyobj.BalloonTipTitle = "New Message"
$notifyobj.BalloonTipText = "C"
$notifyobj.Visible = $True
$notifyobj.ShowBalloonTip(1000)
$notifyobj.Dispose()
```

More info on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8wceh3/why_does_my_script_work_in_iseps_command_but_not/?utm_content=full_comments&utm_medium=message&utm_source=reddit&utm_name=frontpage) thread.

Comment: If you set a "pause" at the end of the script, is there a window displayed?

Comment: There's a console window even when I don't add pause at the end of the script (which disappears after like a second). I want the notification to show without the PS window popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Odd for sure, and there should have been really no reason you should have had to reinstall Windows for your effort. So, something else is impacting this. Hard to say what though.

Try this version to see if you have any / more success. It takes a different approach, but works on my systems.

```
Function Show-Notification 
{            
    Param
    (
        [string]$MessageType,
        [string]$MessageText,
        [string]$MessageTitle
    )            

    #load Windows Forms and drawing assemblies            
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null            

    #define an icon image pulled from PowerShell.exe            
    $Icon=[system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((join-path $pshome powershell.exe))            
    $Notify = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon            
    $Notify.icon = $Icon            
    $Notify.visible = $True 

    #define the tool tip icon based on the message type            
    switch ($messagetype) 
    {            
        "Error"   {$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Error}            
        "Info"    {$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Info}            
        "Warning" {$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Warning}            
        Default   {$MessageIcon = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::None}            
    }            

    #display the balloon tipe            
    $Notify.showballoontip($Notification_timeout,$MessageTitle,$MessageText,$MessageType)            
} 

Show-Notification -MessageType Info -MessageText 'some message' -MessageTitle 'New Alert'
```

[image]

[image]

***Update***

Modifying your posted code to match a few items in mine, allows your code to work in the ISE, console as expected.

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null  
$notifyobj = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
# I don't have your icon, so, using what I know I can reach
$notifyobj.Icon = [system.drawing.icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon((join-path $pshome powershell.exe))
$notifyobj.BalloonTipTitle = "New Message"
$notifyobj.BalloonTipText = "C"
$notifyobj.Visible = $True
$notifyobj.ShowBalloonTip(1000)
$notifyobj.Dispose()
```

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify a few things...the .ps1 script I used never worked with task scheduler (it would only load Powershell.exe or a console window that just vanished without the message showing up) but it did work when I clicked on the .ps1 file but it would load a console window before the message showed up. When I moved to VB it worked when I clicked on the VB file & when I used the VB file with task scheduler; both without the console window popping up before the message showed. It still works with VB but only if I create a new user account then after like a day or two it stops working...

Comment: Actually my comment is incorrect: It worked with task scheduler (it would load a  console window before the message showing up) & when I clicked on the .ps1 file it would also load a console  window before the message showed up. When I moved to VB it worked when I  clicked on the VB file & when I used the VB file with task  scheduler; both without the console window popping up before the message  showed.

Comment: Also, the first script you provided doesn't automatically clear from the notifications menu so even if it did work, I can't use it.